# How to hide Android ActionBar in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, hide, xamarin.forms

How can I hide the `ActionBar` of an `Activity` in `Xamarin.Forms`? I tried the following but none of it worked:

- calling `ActionBar.Hide()` in `OnCreate()`
- setting the theme to `"@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"`

Comment: Are you wanting to hide the ActionBar on some pages, but not on others?  Also are you only using Xamarin.Forms Navigation?, or do you have mixed Activity / AndroidActivity?  If you can package up a small demo of your issue I will take a further look.  My contact details are on my Profile.

Comment: I have just one single `AndroidActivity`, nothing more.

Comment: Have you tried the solution by James on [this](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18290/hiding-the-status-bar-and-the-action-bar-in-android-app) link?, also there is a answer by Allister that suggests to set the size to 0 ?

Comment: Just found it. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just found the solution parallel to @Pete. It seems that this is a bug under `Xamarin.Forms` at the moment.

I added this in my `Styles.xml` and set the theme to my `Activity`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<resources> 
    <style name="NoActionBarTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/invisible_action_bar_style</item>
    </style>
    <style name="invisible_action_bar_style" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:height">0dp</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 12):

you can just hide it in your constructor

```
public partial class MyPage : ContentPage
{
    public MyPage()
    {
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
        InitializeComponent();            
    }        
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer, you can call it anytime too if you need to show/hide ActionBar

Answer (score 1):

The better way to hide the ActionBar with Xamarin.Forms:

```
global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetTitleBarVisibility(Xamarin.Forms.AndroidTitleBarVisibility.Never);
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple fix worked for me. Change the line at the top of your Styles.xml file to look like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
```

To replace the line that looked like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

All you need do is change the word "Dark" to "No" in front of ActionBar.
Search "Theme.MaterialComponents" for a list of Material Components that you can use.